# JUnit: @Rule's overridden apply method not executed under test

Tags: java, junit, rule

I created a JUnit rule to rollback a javax.persistence transaction when any exception occurs (otherwise all further tests will fail since the transaction is in an inconsistent condition). The problem is that my rule will never be executed when the test starts, strictly speaking: the `apply` method is never executed. it does not even work when I put the @Rule declaration into the concrete class and initialize the transactionRule within the test. Here is how it looks like:

**THE RULE**

```
public class TransactionRule implements TestRule
{
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public TransactionRule(EntityManager entityManager)
    {
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Statement apply(Statement base, Description description)
    {
        return new TransactionStatement(base);
    }

    public class TransactionStatement extends Statement
    {
        private final Statement runningTest;

        public TransactionStatement(Statement runningTest)
        {
            this.runningTest = runningTest;
        }

        @Override
        public void evaluate() throws Throwable
        {
            try
            {
                runningTest.evaluate();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (entityManager.getTransaction().isActive())
                {
                    entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**THE ABSTRACT CLASS THAT USES THE RULE**

```
public abstract class AbstractIntegrationTest
{
    //more members vars

    @Rule
    public TransactionRule transactionRule;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpBeforeClass()
    {
        loadProperties();
        entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("MyCuisinePersistenceTestUnit", connectionProperties);
        entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp()
    {
        transactionRule = new TransactionRule(entityManager);

        entityManager.clear();
    }

    //more code
}
```

**THE TEST CLASS WITH THE DEFECTIVE TEST**

```
public class RecipePersistenceITest extends AbstractIntegrationTest
{
    //more tests 

    @Test
    public void persistenceOfRecipeWithUserCategorySuccessful()
    {
        //Test that fails
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I am not entirely sure, but I believe creating the rule in the `@Before` is too late.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test rules are invoked before methods annotated with `@Before`, so trying to assign a rule in `@Before` will have no effect (although I would have expected it to throw an exception instead).

Instead assign the rule on definition (and make the field final), and do any additional config (if necessary) in your `@Before`.

Note that each test method is executed in a new instance of the test class, so defining a rule as a final field is no problem.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, to not let any other tests crash while one test fails, I just had to always create a new entityManager in @Before, so in the end, the rule is not even needed. 
But the question and answer still helps me because in company I had the same problem and wondered why my rule was not executed.

Comment: @Bevor Each test is run in their own instances of the class, you should take advantage of that property. You could for example create and destroy the entity manager in the rule.